# ¿Cómo puedo comentar un código HTML combinado con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Sé que hay varias maneras de añadir comentarios pero ninguna me funciona bien por que sólo se comenta el código HTML y el PHP sigue activo.

Éste es mi código:

```
<!--                                    <div class="row">
                                    <?php 
                                    if($categoria == 4):
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;">Pasos                :      </pre>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php 
                                    if($categoria == 8):
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;">Fondo               :       </pre>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás comentando correctamente el HTML, y aunque se ejecute el PHP y genere HTML adicional éste estará comentado y no se verá.

HTML y PHP son dos cosas independientes (una se interpreta en el servidor y la otra en el cliente), por lo que deberás comentar ambas por separado.

Si comentas en PHP tendrás la ventaja que al cliente no le enviarás el código, ahorrando un poco en ancho de banda (hoy en día despreciable) pero, más importante aún, evitarás enviar HTML que probablemente exponga información que no deseas que conozca.

Si comentas en HTML todo llegará al cliente y éste no verá nada en su navegador, pero como dije anteriormente tienes la desventaja de que estás ejecutando código PHP que podrías ahorrarte y reducir el consumo de CPU de tu servidor.

En tu ejemplo, si creas un comentario abriendo una etiqueta `<?php` antes del HTML podrás comentar ambas cosas a la vez y no se enviará nada al navegador (no se hará uso de `<!-- .. -->` porque no será enviado al cliente):

```php
<?php /* A partir de aquí todo (PHP + HTML) se considera comentario:
<!-- <div class="row">
<?php if($categoria == 4): ?>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;">Pasos                :      </pre>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($categoria == 8): ?>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;">Fondo               :       </pre>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>-->
*/ /* A partir de aquí vuelve a ser HTML */?>
```

Nota: el coloreado de stackoverflow no funciona correctamente con este código, pero todo es comentario desde `/*` hasta el `*/` del final.

Comment: okey una vez mas gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: jaja disculpa recién estoy usando esta página de preguntas y respuestas (que por cierto es muy buena) y gracias  gente como tu que son como ángeles de la programación caídos del cielo xD

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda de nuevo :) Por cierto, he editado una forma de comentar ambas cosas a la vez desde PHP (por lo que no se envía nada al navegador del cliente) por si te sirve de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para comentar en html utilizamos la etiqueta de apertura `<!--` y cerrar `-->`.
Cuando comentas un html que incluye php  estás comentando absolutamente todo aunque te marque el php activo.

De todas maneras si deseas comentar el php también debes utilizar la marca `/*` justo despues de la etiqueta `<?php` y cerrar el comentario con `*/` justo antes de cerrar el php con `?>`.

Para comentar una sola línea de php utilizamos `//` y esto comenta solo la línea donde lo colocas.